# Vuex: Can I use function names of mutations/actions instead of constants?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Is it a good idea to use [function name property](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) instead of constants for actions/mutations, like the code below?

Author of Vuex official documentation says that it is not required to use constants for actions/mutations. So I want to try to use type is based on function name.

Component:

```
this.$store.dispatch(authActions.login.name, { 
  email: this.email, 
  password: this.password 
})
```

Action:

```
async login(context, { email, password }) {
  // some code
}
```

I am waiting for the following answers:

- 1) Yes, you can use it, there are no potential problems with this
  approach.
- 2) Yes, but these problems [problems] can happen.
- 3) No, there are a lot of problems: [problems].

Comment: When you call `authActions.login` you know the name is `login` already right? Or is it a simplified example?

Comment: @Flame, Yes, I do, because I import actions to my component to use actions methods. Login method in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's option number **2)**.

The problem comes when you want to dispatch namespaced modules actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this and it does work, but I noticed when I minify my code for production it stops working.

I suspect there's some code that maps the function names (ie `login()`) to their minified version (ie `h()`) during bundling, and that's breaking things.

I've been trying to figure this out for a while with no luck. I agree defining constants to use as function names, instead of grabbing the name after like `myFunction.name`, is stupid. I'll update my comment if I figure it out. I'll keep trying...